# Error while using message_handler (telebot)

Tags: python, telegram, py-telegram-bot-api

I tried to create my own Telegram bot using pyTelegramBotAPI, telebot. Here is my code:

```
import telebot

bot = telebot.TeleBot("xxxx")

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start', 'help'])
def send_welcome(message):
    bot.reply_to(message, "Howdy, how are you doing?")

bot.polling()
```

But, when I run it I get error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 1, in <module>
    import telebot
  File "/home/rm_coder/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/telebot/__init__.py", line 816
    @util.async()
          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: How are you running the bot? Are you sure you're using 3.6+ ?

Comment: [Known issue](https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI/issues/524)

Answer (score 0):

check that you are using the latest version of python recommended in the [API](https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI).
 (python 3.8 or higher should be fine).

To check it `python3 --version` in the terminal.
If it is not `3.8 or greater` update it.

Then you have to re-download the telegram bot API.
`pip uninstall telebot`
`pip install pyTelegramBotAPI`